# How to make Jackson recognize constructor field names as properties without explicit JsonProperty?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

There is a simple class with parameterized constructor. I'm looking for a way to apply it for JSON deserialization with minimal annotations usage.

How to make Jackson recognize `id` field by its name without explicit `JsonProperty`?

**Class:**

```
public final class MyRec {

    final String id;

    public MyRec1(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Deserialization fails unless annotation `@JsonProperty("id")` is present on the field.

**Deserialization attempt:**

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue("""{"id":"abc"}""", MyRec.class);
```

**Exception:**

```
Cannot construct instance of `sample.MyRec` (although at least one Creator exists): 
cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
  at [Source: (String)"{"id":"abc"}"; line: 1, column: 2]

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException:
Cannot construct instance of `sample.MyRec` (although at least one Creator exists):
  cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
  at [Source: (String)"{"id":"abc"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
  at app//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
```

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It's a documented issue of the Jackson's creator-discovery mechanism (I've provided the links in the answer), and it might be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Parameter names module

To make Jackson capable of detecting the required constructor based on the number of properties **without** making use of data-binding annotations `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` you can add a dependency to **Jackson Modules: Java 8** ([a link to the Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-modules-java8/2.13.3)).

Jackson Modules: Java 8 is an umbrella multi-module which includes [Parameter names module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/2.14/parameter-names).

If you are using Spring Boot, the only thing needed to register the module is to place `ParameterNamesModule` as a Bean into the Spring's Context, and it would be grabbed at the application start-up and registred automatically by the [`JacksonAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.html) while `ObjectMapper` would be configured.

As explained [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/2.14/parameter-names#delegating-creator) you need to provide `JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES` as argument while instantiating the module.

```
@Bean
public ParameterNamesModule parameterNamesModule() {
    return new ParameterNamesModule(JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES);
}
```

If you're not using Spring in your project, then you would need to configure `ObjectMapper` manually:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule(JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES));
```

#### Note

There are **caveats**. Specifically there's an issue with detecting a *single-arg constructor*. Here's a quote from the [module-description](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/2.14/parameter-names):

> **Preconditions:**
>
> - class Person must be compiled with Java 8 compliant compiler with option to store formal parameter names turned on (-parameters option).
>   For more information about Java 8 API for accessing parameter names at
>   runtime see this
> - if there are multiple visible constructors and there is no default constructor, @JsonCreator is required to select constructor for
>   deserialization
> - if used with jackson-databind lower than 2.6.0, @JsonCreator is required. In practice, @JsonCreator is also often required with 2.6.0+
>   due to issues with constructor discovery that will be resolved in 2.7.
> - if class `Person` has a **single argument constructor**, its argument **needs to be annotated** with `@JsonProperty("propertyName")`. This is to
>   **preserve legacy behavior**, see FasterXML/jackson-databind/#1498

So, to make the Jackson recognize a *single-arg constructor*, we need to apply `@JsonProperty` on the argument.

Here's also a mention of this issue [`JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.Mode.html#PROPERTIES) documentation:

> Mode that indicates that the argument(s) for creator are to be bound from matching properties of incoming Object value, using creator argument names (explicit or implicit) to match incoming Object properties to arguments.
>
> **Note** that this mode is currently (2.5) always used for
> multiple-argument creators; the **only ambiguous case is that of a
> single-argument creator**.

---

This behavior **might be fixed** with Jackson 3 as [mentioned here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1498#issuecomment-325795788).

## Java 16 Records

If you're using JDK 16+ in your project, then you can make this final class to be a record.

Records **doesn't** declare a default no-args constructor, instead the compiler generates a so-called *canonical constructor*, declaring all the arguments from the record's header (*refer to the JLS [8.10.4. Record Constructor Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10.4) for more information*).

And Jackson uses *canonical constructor* as a default creator to instantiate records.

The following record would be desirialized without issues:

```
public record MyRec(String id) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Until Java 8, the names of method and constructor parameters were not present in compiled byte code. In Java 8 and later, the `-parameters` needs to be explicitly set to get the parameter names in byte code. If the name is not available in byte code, it is not available through reflection; you'd instead get `arg0`, `arg1`, etc.

Some frameworks have already been updated to use the parameter names, but a lot have not. As far as I know, Jackson belongs to the second group (most likely also to still support older Java versions). You can try to use the `-parameters` flag, but you probably still have to tell Jackson to use the constructor - either using `@JsonProperty` on the constructor parameter, or using `@JsonCreator`.